# The uniqueness of $c$ for an integral to be zero

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f,g$ be integrable on $[a,b]$, and suppose there exists a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\int^b_a\big(f(x)-c\cdot g(x)\big)^2dx=0
\end{equation}
My question is that is such a $c$ unique? If so, why? If not, is there any counterexample?

Edit: As pointed out in comment, $c$ can be anything in the trivial case $f=g=0$. My bad for missing this out. Sorry about that. Therefore I would like to edit my question so that $f,g$ are now assumed to be not zero function.

Comment: If $f=g=0$, $c$ is definitely not unique.

Comment: Oh yes! haha my bad. Thanks. How about if $f,g$ are not zero function?

Comment: We must have $f=cg$ a.e. and if this is true $c$ should be unique.

Comment: MeU, unless you get rid of the square, you question is trivial.

Comment: @AlphaGo, sorry, I missed the square when I made my comment before

Answer (score 5):

As AlphaGo said, by a theorem in measure theory (https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf Lemma 1.49, p. 35 (41 of the pdf document)) a positive integrable function integrates to zero iff it is identically zero almost everywhere, and so the constant $c$ is unique with this property, given by
$$c=f/g\quad a.e.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to develop such uniqueness not by using measure theory? For example is it possible to develop it by elementary calculus or elementary real analysis?

Comment: If you assume, for example, that the functions are continuous it is quite easy. Just take any point where the function is strictly positive. Then it will be positive in an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of that point and so the integral is nonzero. Therefore the function $f-cg$ must be identically zero, hence $c$ is unique, given by $f(x_0)/g(x_0)$, for some $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)\neq 0$.

Comment: Haha yes, I am aware of the case where $f,g$ are continuous. However I am curious about the case in general, i.e., $f,g$ are not necessarily continuous. And that's the case that puzzles me.

Comment: Well... measurable is continuous "a.e" by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem ... So the next generalization is (probably) the one I quote, which is indeed nothing but "elementary" real analysis/measure theory.